# Java Math RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN different results

Tags: java, double, rounding, bigdecimal, decimalformat

It appears that `HALF_EVEN` rounding mode works differently in Java `DecimalFormat` than `BigDecimal`. Is there any way to make the `DecimalFormat` be consistent?

```
// Using BigDecimal scale
System.out.println("Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> " + new BigDecimal("21.255").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
System.out.println("Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> " + new BigDecimal("21.265").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));

// Using DecimalFormat
DecimalFormat cdf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
cdf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); // default anyway
System.out.println("Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> " + cdf.format(21.255));
System.out.println("Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> " + cdf.format(21.265));

Output:
Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> 21.26
Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> 21.26
Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> 21.25
Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> 21.27
```

Comment: That is because of the precision of doubles, 21.255 as double is actually a little bit less than 21.255 exact and 21.265 as double is a little bit more than 21.265 exact. Compare what happens if you use `new BigDecimal(21.255)` (so with a double instead of a string).

Comment: Agreed, and even better, to avoid ugly behaviour, you should use the `String` constructor of `BigDecimal` to get perfectly accurate results

Answer (score 6):

As said in the comment, if you try:

```
Double double1 = new Double(21.255);
BigDecimal bigDecimal1 = new BigDecimal(double1);
System.out.println(bigDecimal1);  //21.254999999999999005240169935859739780426025390625

Double double2 = new Double(21.265);
BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal(double2);
System.out.println(bigDecimal2); //21.2650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
```

You will find that:

- `double 21.255` is a little less than `21.255`
- `double 21.265` is a little greater than `21.265`

You can initiate the input as `BigDecimal` when using `DecimalFormat` to avoid losing accuracy:

```
System.out.println("Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> " + cdf.format(new BigDecimal("21.255")));
//21.26
System.out.println("Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> " + cdf.format(new BigDecimal("21.265")));
//21.26
```

Comment: `df.format(new BigDecimal("320.705"))` still output `320.70`, but it should be `320.71` in `half_even` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran some tests : 
using @Mark Rotteveel solution :

```
cdf.format(new BigDecimal(21.255))

Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> 21.26
Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> 21.26
Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> 21,25
Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> 21,27
```

using the `BigDecimal` String constructor:

```
cdf.format(new BigDecimal("21.255"))

Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> 21.26
Big decimal scale (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> 21.26
Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.255 ==> 21,26
Decimal format (HALF_EVEN) of 21.265 ==> 21,26
```

So clearly, you **have** to use the `String` constructor to get the right result

Answer (score 1):

The value of the double `21.255` is not exactly 21.255, it is actually closer to `21.25499999...`, which means even with rounding mode `HALF_EVEN`, it will round down to `21.25`. Similarly the double `21.265` is actually closer to `21.26500000000000056...` which means it will round up.

You can get the exact same behavior as `DecimalFormat` by using `new BigDecimal(double)` instead of `new BigDecimal(String)`